# Disable Incoming Call Notification

Tags: java, android

I've been writing up some android code that involves rejecting calls for certain telephone numbers and have gotten to the point where I can intercept the call coming in, compare it to a particular number, and then reject it. I am also using the SILENT_MODE setting once I detect that its a number I want to block so there is no sound. However, the call notification still comes up on the screen for a second or two before the call totally stops. Does anyone know how to prevent this? Is this even possible? What about instantly transferring the call to voicemail message and then deleting the message? I also suppose there may be a work around to make the screen go black but that would be a bad user experience. I am using the ITelephony Java class in my implementation. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!!!! Below is my code so far:

```
   public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
   {
    private ITelephony telephonyService;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                String phoneNumber = extras
                        .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                // Will eventually retrieve a list from shared preferences
                // instead of contacts.
                contactsMap = mypackage.com.util.ContactsUtil
                        .getPhoneContacts(context);
                Log.e("DEBUG", phoneNumber);

                // testing purposes...
                if (phoneNumber.equals("4133972057"))
                {
                    AudioManager aManager = (AudioManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    aManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    Class c;
                    try
                    {
                        c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                        m.setAccessible(true);
                        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);


                        telephonyService.endCall();
                    }
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (InvocationTargetException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (RemoteException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```